# Primefaces keyboard component doesn't set value in backend

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

i am using the primefaces keyboard to search for some articles in the application. My problem is that i have a commandButton that goes to a method in the managed bean which does the search. When arriving in the managed bean the string assigned to the keyboard component is empty.

Here is the part with the component in jsf file

```
<h:panelGroup id="ric_tastiera" layout="block"
        style="display:none; overflow:hidden; height:180px;">
            <p:keyboard id="qwerty" value="#{dpDisponibilita2.pressed_letter}" layout="qwertyBasic" />
            <p:commandButton action="#{dpDisponibilita2.caricaArticoliDaLettera}" value="Search" ajax="true" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

What i am missing or doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have h:form ?can you share managebean codes ?

Comment: Exactly this part it's outside a form....i will include it in a form right now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: did it worked with h:form ?

Comment: For the moment i have other errors, unrelated to this one. Once i fix them i will let you know if it works or not

Comment: After adding the h:form tag it works, please put your comment as an answer so that i can vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each action should enclosed by a `<h:form>` to fire the action. Actions will not fire if there is no enclosing `h:form`.

It is better to use `h:form` tag to cover the whole page. You should be avoid using nested forms.

**See also**

[commandLink/commandButton/ajax backing bean action/listener method not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/892994)